# Length 6 and 7 "date" variables, convert to actual dates?/ working from right to left

Tags: sas

My `data` looks like:

```
2122014
5032014
12012014
1212014
```

How do I get these to actual date variables? I primarily work in `R`. My assumption was I could take the last 4, make that the year. Take the next 2, make that the day, then take whatever is left over and make that the month, but I do not know how to work from right to left, and even if I could, how to make these strings proper character strings to manipulate (I tried to convert to character and many strings lost the final 2 characters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAS will happily figure things out, assuming they're figureable.  1212014 for example is either 12/1/2014 or 1/21/2014, and SAS has a consistent choice it makes there (1/21).  Just use the full width informat.

```
data have;
  input charvar $;
  datevar=input(charvar,mmddyy8.);
  put charvar= datevar= date9.;
  datalines;
2122014
5032014
12012014
1212014
;;;;
run;
```